# Printing Issue In small size of Paper

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Hi I have created Id card using silverlight.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ICartPrinting.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="409" d:DesignWidth="360"  xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="410" Width="360"  >
    <Border x:Name="AreaToPrint" BorderThickness="1"  BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,30,0,0" >
        <Grid x:Name="GridAreaToPrint">



            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,15,0,0" Name="lbl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="CSC" />

            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,15,0,0" Name="lblCSC" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180"  Content="CSC" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,15,0,0" Name="lbl2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,40,0,0" Name="lbl3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Name" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,40,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212"  Content="Name" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,40,0,0" Name="lbl4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,65,0,0" Name="lbl5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Address" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,65,0,0" Name="lbl6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,65,0,0" Name="lblAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212"  Content="Adderss" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,90,0,0" Name="lbl7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Code No." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,90,0,0" Name="lbl8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,90,0,0" Name="lblCode" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"  Content="Code" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,90,0,0" Name="lbl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Rank" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,90,0,0" Name="lbl12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,90,0,0" Name="lblRank" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"  Content="Rank" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,115,0,0" Name="lbl9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Join Date" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,115,0,0" Name="lbl10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,115,0,0" Name="lblDOF" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"  Content="Join Date" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,115,0,0" Name="lbl47" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Valid" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,115,0,0" Name="lbl48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,115,0,0" Name="lblValid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78"  Content="Valid" />

            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,140,0,0" Name="lbl13" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="S.R." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,140,0,0" Name="lblSR" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Content="sr" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,140,0,0" Name="lbl23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,160,0,0" Name="lbl14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="S.D." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,160,0,0" Name="lbl24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,160,0,0" Name="lblSD" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="sd" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,180,0,0" Name="lbl15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="D.O." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,180,0,0" Name="lbl25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,180,0,0" Name="lblDO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="do" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,200,0,0" Name="lbl16" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Z.O." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,200,0,0" Name="lbl26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,200,0,0" Name="lblZO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="zo" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,220,0,0" Name="lbl17" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="E.M.(I)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,220,0,0" Name="lbl27" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,220,0,0" Name="lblEM1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EM(I)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,240,0,0" Name="lbl18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="E.M.(R)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,240,0,0" Name="lbl28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,240,0,0" Name="lblEMR" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EM(R)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,260,0,0" Name="lbl19" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="EMH" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,260,0,0" Name="lbl29" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,260,0,0" Name="lblEMH" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EMH" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,280,0,0" Name="lbl20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="EMH(2)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,280,0,0" Name="lbl30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,280,0,0" Name="lblEMH2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EMH(2)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,300,0,0" Name="lbl21" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="EMH(4)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,300,0,0" Name="lbl22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,300,0,0" Name="lblEMH4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EMH(4)" />

            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,140,0,0" Name="lbl31" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="S.O." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,140,0,0" Name="lbl32" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,140,0,0" Name="lblSO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="so" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,160,0,0" Name="lbl33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="S.I." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,160,0,0" Name="lbl34" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,160,0,0" Name="lblSI" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="si" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,180,0,0" Name="lbl35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="R.O." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,180,0,0" Name="lbl36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,180,0,0" Name="lblRO" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="ro" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,200,0,0" Name="lbl37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="E.M." />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,200,0,0" Name="lbl38" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,200,0,0" Name="lblEM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EM" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,220,0,0" Name="lbl39" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="E.M.(II)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,220,0,0" Name="lbl40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,220,0,0" Name="lblEM2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="em(2)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,240,0,0" Name="lbl41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="E.M.(C)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,240,0,0" Name="lbl42" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,240,0,0" Name="lblEMC" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EM(C)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,260,0,0" Name="lbl43" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="EMH(1)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,260,0,0" Name="lbl44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,260,0,0" Name="lblEMH1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EMH(1)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,280,0,0" Name="lbl45" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" FontWeight="Bold" Content="EMH(3)" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,280,0,0" Name="lbl46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="9" FontWeight="Bold" Content=":" />
            <sdk:Label Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,280,0,0" Name="lblEMH3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"  Content="EMH(3)" />
            <TextBox Height="31" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,330,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="                       107,MONALISA COMPLEX,,NR.KALYAN"  Foreground="White" Width="410"  />
            <TextBox Height="28" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,350,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="              HOTEL,SAYAJIGUNJ,VADODARA,Vadodara,Gujarat"  Foreground="White" Width="410"  />
        </Grid>

    </Border>
    <Button Content="Print" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,0,0" Name="PrintButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="PrintButton_Click" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is an Id card. When I print this on A4 size paper, content is printing on Left upper size of paper but when i print on small size of paper then only half portion of right side is print and half portion of left side is cut off. Can i print this on center of Page? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your print method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing by looping through all your labels then just printing the text? or by converting your "GridAreaToPrint" to a UI element then printing that?

If you're converting to a UI element then you're already half way there. You would have to specify somewhere weather you wanted to print A4, A5 or whatever, then depending on the users choice you could scale your grid to fit appropriately. (With trail and error)

If you didn't want to fit to page, you could just adjust the X & Y values (`scaleTransform.ScaleX` & `caleTransform.ScaleX`) until your id card is where you want it.

See this for reference : [Silverlight printing: Fit to page](http://jacekjura.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/silverlight-printing-fit-to-page.html)

It should contain all you need